# What Are the Ideas Behind Variations of the Coin Change Problem?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, coin-change

> Problem: given a set of `n` coins of unique face values, and a value
>   `change`, find number of ways of making change for `change`.

Assuming we can use a denomination more than once, here's the pseudocode I came up with

```
1. NUM-WAYS(denom[], n, change)
2.   dp = [change + 1][n + 1]
3.   for i = 0 to n
4      dp[i][0] = 1
5.   xs = denom.sorted

6.   for i = 1 to change
7.     for j = 1 to n
8.       if xs[j - 1] > i
9.         dp[i][j] = dp[i][j - 1]
10.      else
11.        dp[i][j] = dp[i - xs[j - 1]][j] + dp[i][j - 1]

12.  return dp[change][n]
```

The above algorithm is clear to me. However, if we are only allowed to use a denomination once, then line 11 changes to `dp[i - xs[j - 1]][j - 1] + dp[i][j - 1]`, as if we are not allowed to use the current denomination at all. I'm failing to wrap my head around this. Can you explain this?

Here're some test runs:

```
Change: 3, denominations: [8, 3, 1, 2]
11111
01111
01222
01233

// use once
Change: 3, denominations: [8, 3, 1, 2]
11111
01111
00111
00122

Change: 4, denominations: [3, 1, 2]
1111
0111
0122
0123
0134

// use once
Change: 4, denominations: [3, 1, 2]
1111
0111
0011
0012
0001
```

Comment: Try to understand the meaning of each cell in the dynamic programming table.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus that clears it up. Why didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here, answering my own question for the greater good of mankind.

Let `dp[i][j]` denote the solution to the `[i,j]`-th subproblem; that is, `dp[i][j]` is the number of ways to make change for the amount `i`, using coins `j` through `n`.

#### Coin Change Problem with Repetition

```
dp[i - xs[j - 1]][j] + // 1
    dp[i][j - 1]       // 2
```

1. Use coin `j`, and since there is no constraint on the denominations, solve the smaller subproblem using the same denomination.
2. Don't use coin `j`.

#### Coin Change Problem without Repetition

```
dp[i - xs[j - 1]][j - 1] + // 1
    dp[i][j - 1]           // 2
```

1. Use coin `j`, and since we used coin `j` for this subproblem, we can't use it for any other.
2. Don't use coin `j`.